# How to reorganize the graphs in the GraphicGrid in a reopened notebook without re-generating them

Tags: graphics

How to reorganize (add some and remove some within the same notebook) the graphs in the GraphicGrid in a previously saved notebook that was closed and reopened, without re-evaluation to re-generate those single graphs?

Comment: So you mean [something like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tPBZN.gif)? I clicked on the grid, then clicked on the graph I wanted, copied and pasted into a new cell, and then typed a name for the plot into the cell and evaluated it.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much! So the trick is to give new names and re-evaluate the copied single graphs. Suggest Mathematica to stress this in the GraphicGrid page, this trick just does not pop up for learners like me.

Comment: As stated above,  you can reuse any existing (non-rasterized)  `Graphics`  or `Graphics3D` expression easily if it's displayed, as the image contains thr plotted  data,  options etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is an extended comment on a comment made by the OP, not an answer.

> Suggest Mathematica to stress this in the GraphicGrid page

[`GraphicsGrid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsGrid.html) would not be the a good place to discuss this input technique because it can be applied much more generally in *Mathematica*. Further, it receives a discussion in a section of the Documentation Center article, [Generalized Input](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GeneralizedInput.html). I recommend you read that article -- it is a tutorial aimed at new *Mathematica* users such as yourself.

There is also a short article [Graphics as Input](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InteractiveGraphicsDirectOutput.html) that is relevant to your question.

P.S. I found these articles by typing "graphics input" into the Documentation Center search field. I mention this to remind you that one can type quite general phrases in the the Documentation Center search field and get some pretty intelligent hits, much like when searching on Google.